# Adding resource to project-specific SBT autoplugins

Tags: scala, sbt

SBT lets you define autoplugins specific to your project by putting them in `./project`.

I'm trying to add resources to one such autoplugin - by which I mean something that it could access through a call to `getClass.getResourceAsStream`.

I have, however, not been able to work out how to do that, or even if it was possible. There's no documentation that I could find on the subject, and the obvious (simply putting resources in `./project` with the plugin) fails.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to place your resource in `./project/src/main/resources/`

For a quick demonstration that this works, assume the file name is `test.txt`, put the following in your `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val hello = taskKey[Unit]("prints the content of test.txt")

hello := println(IO.readStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("test.txt")))
```